# ASP.NET RangeValidator for date of birth with culture fr-BE

Tags: asp.net, globalization, rangevalidator

I have an ASP.NET web forms application with a textbox for entering the date of birth.
There is a RangeValidator for the date of birth.

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date of   birth." Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtDate" Type="Date" />
```

In the code behind I set the minimum and maximum allowed values like this:

```
RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).ToShortDateString();
RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

This usually seems to work fine. However, a user has set his culture to fr-BE.
This culture uses only two digits for the year.
The minimum value then becomes "01-01-00" which the range validator interprets as 1st January 2000.
Therefore the user cannot enter a date of birth before 2000.

How can I set the range validator's minimum value so that it works correctly for all cultures?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [someone](http://nwije.blogspot.com/2011/08/asp-rangevalidator-cannot-convert.html) had this kind of trouble before.

In the page set the property `MinimumValue` like the following:
' />